# class variable become empty in multiprocessing pool.map

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a class variable in a Utils class.

```
class Utils:
    _raw_data = defaultdict(list)

    @classmethod
    def raw_data(cls):
        return cls._raw_data.copy()

    @classmethod
    def set_raw_data(cls, key, data):
        cls._raw_data[key] = data
```

The _raw_data was filled with key and value pairs before it was being read.

```
...
data = [ipaddress.IPv4Network(address) for address in ip_addresses]
Utils.set_raw_data(device_name, data)
```

But when I try to execute a function in multiprocessing Pool.map that reads the raw_data from Utils class, it returns empty list.

This is the method from the parent class

```
class Parent:
    ...
    def evaluate_without_prefix(self, devices):
        results = []
        print(Utils.raw_data())  <------ this print shows that the Utils.raw_data() is empty
        for network1, network2 in itertools.product(Utils.raw_data()[devices[0]], Utils.raw_data()[devices[1]]):
            if network1.subnet_of(network2):
                results.append((devices[0], network1, devices[1], network2))
            if network2.subnet_of(network1):
                results.append((devices[1], network2, devices[0], network1))

        return results
```

and in the child class, I execute the method from the parent class, with multiprocessing pool.

```
class Child(Parent):
    ...
    def execute(self):
        pool = Pool(os.cpu_count() - 1)
        devices = list(itertools.combinations(list(Utils.raw_data().keys()), 2))
        results = pool.map(super().evaluate_without_prefix, devices)
        return results
```

The print() in the Parent class shows that the raw_data() is empty, but the variable actually has data, devices variable in Child class actually get data from the raw_data() but when it enters the multiprocessing pool, the raw_data() becomes empty. Any reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be as follows:

The class data created in your main process must be serialized/de-serialized using `pickle` so that it can be passed from the main process's address space to the address spaces of the processes in the multiprocessing pool that needs to work with these objects. But the class data in question is an instance of class `Parent` since you are calling one of its methods, i.e. `valuate_without_prefix`. But nowhere in that instance is there a reference to class `Util` or anything that would cause the multiprocessing pool to be serializing the `Util` class along with the `Parent` instance. Consequently, when that method references class `Util` in any of the processes, a new `Util` will be created and, of course, it will not have its dictionary initialized.

I think the simplest change is to:

1. Make attribute `_raw_data` an *instance* attribute rather than a class attribute (by the way, according to your current usage, there is no need for this to be a `defaultdict`).
2. Create an instance of class `Util` named `util` and initialize the dictionary via this reference.
3. Use the *initializer* and *initargs* arguments of the `multiprocessing.Pool` constructor to initialize each process in the multiprocessing pool to have a global variable named `util` that will be a copy of the `util` instance created by the main process.

So I would organize the code along the following lines:

```python
class Utils:

    def __init__(self):
        self._raw_data = {}

    def raw_data(self):
        # No need to make a copy ???
        return self._raw_data.copy()

    def set_raw_data(self, key, data):
        self._raw_data[key] = data

def init_processes(utils_instance):
    """
    Initialize each process in the process pool with global variable utils.
    """
    global utils
    utils = utils_instance

class Parent:
    ...
    def evaluate_without_prefix(self, devices):
        results = []
        print(utils.raw_data())
        for network1, network2 in itertools.product(utils.raw_data()[devices[0]], utils.raw_data()[devices[1]]):
            results.append([network1, network2])
        return results

class Child(Parent):
    ...
    def execute(self, utils):
        pool = Pool(os.cpu_count() - 1, initializer=init_processes, initargs=(utils,))
        # No need to make an explicit list (map will do that for you) ???
        devices = list(itertools.combinations(list(utils.raw_data().keys()), 2))
        results = pool.map(super().evaluate_without_prefix, devices)
        return results

def main():
    utils = Utils()
    # Initialize utils:   
    ...
    data = [ipaddress.IPv4Network(address) for address in ip_addresses]
    utils.set_raw_data(device_name, data)

    child = Child()
    results = child.execute(utils)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Further Explanation**

The following program's main process calls class method `Foo.set_x` to update class attribute `x` to the value of 10 before creating a multiprocessing pool and invoking worker function `worker`, which prints out the value of `Foo.x`.

On Windows, which uses OS `spawn` to create new processes, the process in the pool is initialized prior to calling the worker function essentially by launching a new Python interpreter and re-executing the source program executing every statement at global scope. Hence the class definition of `Foo` is created by the Python interpreter compiling it; there is no pickling involved. But `Foo.x` will be 0.

The same program run on Linux, which uses OS `fork` to create new processes, inherits a copy-on-write address space from the main process. Therefore, it will have a copy of the `Foo` class as it existed at the time the multiprocessing pool was created and `Foo.x` *will* be 10.

My solution above, which uses a pool initializer to set a global variable in each pool's process's address space to the value of the `Util` instance, is what is required for Windows platforms and will work also for Linux. An alternative, of course, is to pass the `Util` instance as an additional argument to your worker function instead of using a pool initializer, but this is generally not as efficient because generally the number of processes in the pool is less than the number of times the worker function is being invoked so less pickling will be required with the pool initializer method.

```python
from multiprocessing import Pool

class Foo:
    x = 0

    @classmethod
    def set_x(cls, x):
        cls.x = x

def worker():
    print(Foo.x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Foo.set_x(10)
    pool = Pool(1)
    pool.apply(worker)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, that clears my doubt. But there is 1 more thing, the reason I uses classmethod is to avoid a new Utils instance be created in each process like you've said, and as far as I understand class methods/attributes should retain it's value across every instance that has been created by any process, what did I missed here?

Comment: What you are missing is this: You have a process pool of N processes and therefore N distinct address spaces. One way or another you need to transmit `Util`'s state to those N address spaces using `pickle`; you cannot share a single copy of state across these different address spaces. Efficiency-wise if makes no difference whether that state is represented as class attributes or instance attributes. But, as I tried to explain, if you pickle a class, the class attributes will only have their initial assigned values per the class definition. So you *must* use instance attributes.

Comment: In other words, you cannot avoid Util instances being created in each process. If you were dealing certain structures, such as `multiprocessing.Array`, these *are* in shared memory and one copy could be shared across multiple processes. But that is not your situation.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the patient and detailed explaination. Really appreciate that.

Comment: I've updated the answer to add a further explanation.